# How do I navigate from child View to it's group View in ExpandableListView on Android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Each child in my ExpandableListView builds a context menu. In my OnCreateContextMenuListener() I need to access some of the TextViews that are displaying data associated with the child's group. ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup() tells me which group is the child's parent, but I've been unable to figure out how to use this to get a handle to the group View that the TextViews live on. What API am I not seeing?

Or is there a better way to get handles to the Views associated with a child's parent group?